# Calling an object from different classes

Tags: java, class

I have a main class to run a BMI calculator class which calculates BMI info (body mass index) with fields for name, age, sex, height, and weight.
There is also a WaistToHip calculator class to calculate waist-to-hip ratio with fields
waist and hip.
However, when I wanted to create a
BodyFat calculator I need the height and waist from both classes.
How am I suppose to call these in my body fat calculator class for my formula?

```
public class body_fat_calculation {
    private double neck;
    private double CBF;
    waist_to_hip_ratio waist;
    bmiCalculator height;

    public body_fat_calculation(double neck) {
        super();
        this.neck = neck;
    }

    public double getCBF() {
        return CBF;
    }

    public void setCBF(double cBF) {
        CBF = cBF;
    }

    public double getNeck() {
        return neck;
    }

    public void setNeck(double neck) {
        this.neck = neck;
    }

    public double Round(double Rval, int Rpl){
        double p = Math.pow(10, Rpl);
        Rval=Rval*p;
        double tmp = Math.round(Rval);
        return tmp/p;
    }

    public void calculateWTHR(){
        CBF= Round((495/(1.0324 - 0.19077 * Math.log10((waist)-(neck)) + 0.15456 * Math.log10(height)) - 450),2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have got in code and then we can go from there

Comment: @Prateek hi there, is this enough?

Comment: First thing first. Why you have `constructor` setting `neck` and then `setNeck` setting neck again? And your `body_fat_calculation` isn't extending any base class so why is `super` there?

Comment: why are you calling `super()`? Is `body_fat_calculation` supposed to be a subclass of another? You should show All your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this?  If you notice I have added two parameters to the `BodyFatCalculator` class - waist and height.

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(string[] args){

    // I assume you will want to use a scanner to get user input to set these variables dynamically
    // for the sake of the example, I have set them myself.
    double height = 1.82; // meters
    double weight = 170.0;
    double waist = 35.0;
    double hip = 40.0;
    double neck = 7.1;
    String name = "Dave";
    String sex = "M";
    int age = 20;

    // create new BMI Calculator to figure out body mass index
    BMICalculator bmiCalc = new BMICalculator(name, age, sex, height, weight);
    double bmi = bmiCalc.calculateBmi(); // calculate body mass index

    WaistToHipCalculator waistHipCalc = new WaistToHipCalculator(waist, hip);
    double whr = waistHipCalc.calculateWhr(); // calculate waist to hip ratio

    BodyFatCalculator bfCalc = new BodyFatCalculator(neck, height, waist);
    double bf = bfCalc.calculateBf(); // calculate body fat

    // print results
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice of you to include the main. I will upload the rest of the codes. So it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are more nouns.  A verb should be a method.  With a class called BodyFatCalculation I think you're trying too hard to use a lot of classes.  Just have a Body (noun) class with calculateBodyMassIndex and calculateBodyFat (verbs) as methods.  You could create a Dimensions class with height and waist in it (with getters and setters as needed) and keep an instance of that inside the Body class, but that's overkill here.